# Redirecting all http requests to https in apache

Tags: apache

I am using Apache in server side.I want to redirect all HTTP requests which are coming to server into HTTPS.

My question:
    How i can configure httpd.conf for This?
For Example:Suppose user entered http://doc.com/
    i want redirect it to https://doc.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires `mod_rewrite` but is able to keep query strings:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This doesn’t and is lighter on the server:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^(.*)$ https://doc.com/$1
```

If you just want to redirect all nōn-HTTPS requests to the start page, use:

```
RedirectMatch permanent . https://doc.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
```